# How to access file included in app bundle in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, file, read-write

I know there are a few questions pertaining to this, but they're in Objective-C.

How can I access a `.txt` file included in my app using Swift **on an actual iPhone**? I want to be able to read and write from it. [Here](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil) are my project files if you want to take a look. I'm happy to add details if necessary.

Comment: “I want to be able to read and write from it.” You cannot. When installed on a device, the app bundle is **read-only**. You can read a file in your app bundle but you cannot write to it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Simply by searching in the app bundle for the resource

```
var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file", withExtension: "txt")
```

However you can't write to it because it is in the app resources directory and you have to create it in the document directory to write to it

```
var documentsDirectory: NSURL?
var fileURL: NSURL?

documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
fileURL = documentsDirectory!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")

if (fileURL!.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)) {
    print("file exist")
}else{
    print("file doesnt exist")
    NSData().writeToURL(fileURL!,atomically:true)
}
```

now you can access it from **fileURL**

**EDIT - 28 August 2018**

This is how to do it in **Swift 4.2**

```
var filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")
```

To create it in the document directory

```
if let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
   let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
   do {
       if try fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable() {
           print("file exist")
       } else {
           print("file doesnt exist")
           do {
            try Data().write(to: fileURL)
           } catch {
               print("an error happened while creating the file")
           }
       }
   } catch {
       print("an error happened while checking for the file")
   }
}
```

Comment: By "it" you mean the writeable file copied to the document directory?

Comment: "now you can access it from fileURL" by it i mean the file created not the included and its writable

Comment: the file is not copied its a new empty file

Comment: could you be more specific of how to make directory in document directory? What's the name of the directory? is it Document, or Documents? Thanks

Comment: How more specific? the answer was about how to access a file not how to create directories.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3**, based on [Karim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580536/597020).

**Reading**

You can read files included in an app’s bundle through the bundle’s resource:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"filename", withExtension: "txt")
```

**Writing**

However, you can’t write there. You will need to create a copy, preferably in the Documents directory:

```
func makeWritableCopy(named destFileName: String, ofResourceFile originalFileName: String) throws -> URL {
    // Get Documents directory in app bundle
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
        fatalError("No document directory found in application bundle.")
    }

    // Get URL for dest file (in Documents directory)
    let writableFileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(destFileName)

    // If dest file doesn’t exist yet
    if (try? writableFileURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) == nil {
        // Get original (unwritable) file’s URL
        guard let originalFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: originalFileName, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Cannot find original file “\(originalFileName)” in application bundle’s resources.")
        }

        // Get original file’s contents
        let originalContents = try Data(contentsOf: originalFileURL)

        // Write original file’s contents to dest file
        try originalContents.write(to: writableFileURL, options: .atomic)
        print("Made a writable copy of file “\(originalFileName)” in “\(documentsDirectory)\\\(destFileName)”.")

    } else { // Dest file already exists
        // Print dest file contents
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: writableFileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("File “\(destFileName)” already exists in “\(documentsDirectory)”.\nContents:\n\(contents)")
    }

    // Return dest file URL
    return writableFileURL
}
```

Example usage:

```
let stuffFileURL = try makeWritableCopy(named: "Stuff.txt", ofResourceFile: "Stuff.txt")
try "New contents".write(to: stuffFileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Answer (score 12):

Just a quick update for using this code with Swift 4:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource:"YourFile", withExtension: "FileExtension")
```

And the following has been updated to account for writing the file out:

```
var myData: Data!

func checkFile() {
    if let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("YourFile.extension")
        do {
            let fileExists = try fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable()
            if fileExists {
                print("File exists")
            } else {
                print("File does not exist, create it")
                writeFile(fileURL: fileURL)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func writeFile(fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        try myData.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This particular example is not the most flexible, but with a little bit of work you can easily pass in your own file names, extensions and data values.

Answer (score 10):

## Property Wrapper - Fetch and convert to correct data type

This simple wrapper helps you to load any file from any bundle in a cleanest way:

```
@propertyWrapper struct BundleFile<DataType> {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let fileManager: FileManager = .default
    let bundle: Bundle = .main
    let decoder: (Data) -> DataType

    var wrappedValue: DataType {
        guard let path = bundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: type) else { fatalError("Resource not found: \(name).\(type)") }
        guard let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: path) else { fatalError("Can not load file at: \(path)") }
        return decoder(data)
    }
}
```

---

#### Usage:

```
@BundleFile(name: "avatar", type: "jpg", decoder: { UIImage(data: $0)! } )
var avatar: UIImage
```

<sub>You can define any decoder to match your needs</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Get File From Bundle in Swift 5.1

```
//For Video File
let stringPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "(Your video file name)", ofType: "mov")

let urlVideo = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Your video file name", withExtension: "mov")
```

Answer (score 2):

Bundles are read only. You can use `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource` to access the file as read-only, but for read-write access you need to copy your document to Documents folder or tmp folder.

Answer (score 2):

Bundles can be written. You can use `Bundle.main.path` to overwrite file by adding it into `Copy Bundles Resource`.

[image: Project -> Target -> Build Pharse -> Copy Bundles Resource]

Answer (score 0):

I have to use a file from another bundle. So, following code worked for me. Needful when you work with a frameworks.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: ViewController.self)
let fileName = bundle.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "json")
```