# Why can't I get the filePath although I save my file properly and see it?

Tags: swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to write/read to the bundle and I use the below reference from StackOverflow:

[How to access file included in app bundle in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580015/how-to-access-file-included-in-app-bundle-in-swift)

which looks like good code and should work fine.

```
if let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
   let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
   do {
       if try fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable() {
           print("file exist")
       } else {
           print("file doesnt exist")
           do {
            try Data().write(to: fileURL)
           } catch {
               print("an error happened while creating the file")
           }
       }
   } catch {
       print("an error happened while checking for the file")
   }
}
```

To get filepath:

```
var filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")
```

I can save the file but somehow I can never find the file path by

```
var filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")
```

I cannot get any of the extensions. I even can see the saved file in my app's data under Devices in XCode which looks great but I can't find it by `filePath`​. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at it this way:

- `Bundle.main` is your app; `Bundle.main.url` looks for the file *inside* your app. (That's why the linked answer is called "How to access file *included in app bundle* in Swift?")
- The `documentDirectory` is *outside* your app, namely (get this), it's the Documents directory.

So you are saving the file *outside* your app and then looking for the file *inside* your app. That's not where it is, so that's not going to work.