# Read and Update into JSON file in main app bundle

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I have a JSON file witch copied locally into xcode which I can read it through the main bundle.
But then I have problem update this JSON file because everytime i write into a new JSON file create in app document folder.

Here are the sample JSON file

```
[
{
    "id": "5c8a80f52dfee238898d64cf",
    "firstName": "Phoebe",
    "lastName": "Monroe",
    "email": "phoebemonroe@furnafix.com",
    "phone": "(903) 553-3410"
},
{
    "id": "5c8a80f575270ddb54a18f86",
    "firstName": "Lidia",
    "lastName": "Wilkins",
    "email": "lidiawilkins@furnafix.com",
    "phone": "(997) 482-3866"
}
]
```

Here are the code which I update the JSON file

```
  let mainUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: ".json")!

    let json = JSON(contact)
    let hello = json.arrayObject
    let str = hello?.description
    let data = str!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    do{
    try data.write(to: mainUrl, options: [])
        } catch {
                print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access file included in app bundle in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580015/how-to-access-file-included-in-app-bundle-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save the file in main bundle again as it's read-only , you need to copy it to say documents/library folder where you can read/write

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let from = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!

        let to = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("result.json")

        do {

            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: from, to: to)

            print(try FileManager.default.contents(atPath: to.path))

            let wer = Data("rerree".utf8 )

            try wer.write(to: to)

            print(try FileManager.default.contents(atPath: to.path))

        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can i know how to do it? because I cant find any guide on this