# How do you access a file from inside an app directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

When using NSBundle, is there a macro such as `$(APP_BUNDLE)` or something similar, so that I can use a specific file?

Comment: You would normally use the `func url(forResource: String?, withExtension: String?) -> URL?` method on a bundle to access files shipped (bundled) with your app. To use files created by your app you would use the file manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access file included in app bundle in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580015/how-to-access-file-included-in-app-bundle-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [`NSBundle.mainBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1410786-mainbundle) which returns a reference to the `NSBundle` for the application. Using this and the various instance methods provided by `NSBundle` you may then determine the paths/URLs of the files packaged within the application bundle.